# Second role execution overrides default parameter value

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-role

I have an ansible role that defines two parameters and a default for the second one.

`roles/upstream/tasks/main.yml`:

```
---
- debug:
    msg: "Parameter in upstream is {{param}} and param2 is {{param2}}"
```

`roles/upstream/defaults/main.yml`:

```
---
param2: []
```

And then this exemplary play:

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role: upstream
      vars:
        param: 21
    - role: upstream
      vars:
        param: 42
        param2: test
```

When I execute this, I see the following:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [upstream : debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Parameter in upstream is 21 and param2 is test"
}

TASK [upstream : debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Parameter in upstream is 42 and param2 is test"
}
```

What is the rationale that the second call to the role also overrides the default for `param2` for the other call and how to avoid this?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/926732/197039

Comment: @techraf thanks, that prevents this problem, but also makes variables inaccessible to other roles... hmmm...

Comment: Because roles in Ansible were originally just an organisational feature. Variables can be play-scoped, or task-scoped, but not role-scoped (there are also extravars, different story). With `vars` inside `roles` section of a play, they are first read as play variables (last value wins), then for each task inside a role the `vars` from that role declaration is applied.

Comment: @techraf I see the technical reasons, but that is extremely counter-intuitive and I see no way to work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you observe is expected.

Roles in Ansible were originally just an organisational feature. Variables can be play-scoped, or task-scoped, but not role-scoped (there are also extravars, facts, magic variables behaving differently, but not relevant here).

With `vars` inside the `roles` section of a play, they are first read as play variables (last value defined wins), then for each task inside a role the `vars` from that role declaration is applied.

---

To avoid the problem, you should use use [`include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html) or [`import_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_role_module.html) module  in `tasks` (or `pre_tasks`).

Then, per your additional requirement in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100250/second-role-execution-overrides-default-parameter-value#comment91159258_52100250):

> [this] makes variables inaccessible to other roles...

You can make the `defaults` and `vars` defined in roles visible outside of the roles by setting [a new parameter `public` in Ansible 2.7](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.7.html#include-role-and-import-role-variable-exposure) (in development as of writing this answer).

---

Final solution:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: upstream
        public: true
      vars:
        param: 21

    - debug:
        var: param2

    - include_role:
        name: upstream
      vars:
        param: 42
        param2: test
```

Comment: Thanks. Apart from the new `public` feature, this the approach I came up with already.